# CKEditor Glyphicons Plugin: Move Icon doesn't work

Tags: ckeditor, glyphicons

I'm using CKEditor 4.5.6 for an WebsiteBuilder and I added this Glyphicons plugin:

[Glyphicon CKEditor Plugin](https://www.michaeljanea.com/ckeditor/bootstrap-glyphicon)

My problem is that when I want to move the icon, it disappears and got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: el.find is not a function
    at getFirstTextNode (plugin.js?t=FB9E:2150)
    at preserveSpaces (plugin.js?t=FB9E:2121)
    at Repository.wrapElement (plugin.js?t=FB9E:699)
    at a.<anonymous> (plugin.js?t=FB9E:2920)
    at a.q (ckeditor.js:10)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
    at CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor.toHtml (ckeditor.js:300)
    at ckeditor.js:373
    at b.insertHtml (ckeditor.js:341)
getFirstTextNode @ plugin.js?t=FB9E:2150
preserveSpaces @ plugin.js?t=FB9E:2121
wrapElement @ plugin.js?t=FB9E:699
(anonymous) @ plugin.js?t=FB9E:2920
q @ ckeditor.js:10
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:12
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @ ckeditor.js:13
toHtml @ ckeditor.js:300
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:373
insertHtml @ ckeditor.js:341
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:351
q @ ckeditor.js:10
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:12
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @ ckeditor.js:13
insertHtml @ ckeditor.js:254
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:653
q @ ckeditor.js:10
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:12
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @ ckeditor.js:13
r @ ckeditor.js:626
internalDrop @ ckeditor.js:657
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:647
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:647
q @ ckeditor.js:10
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:12
CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire @ ckeditor.js:13
e @ ckeditor.js:644
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:647
q @ ckeditor.js:10
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:12
(anonymous) @ ckeditor.js:52
```

Did someone meet this problem. Can it be resolved in an wasy way? I'm using CKEditor for the first time, so I don't have big experiences with it.

P.S.: I've already used the plugin discussion to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a big refactor of the `widget` plugin, which broke a few plugins depending on this one (eg. placeholder, token)

This is the share of the commit

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/2fca8e6248aebab164133e9cd97403cb2de9a006

So you will need to reach out to the maintainer of the widget

If the plugin is not updated, you will need to use old version of widget.